# Override hover pseudo class CSS attributes when specific html-class is set

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display sets of images with up and down navigation in form of arrows. I have added

```
cursor:pointer;
```

to the arrows on hover to emphasize the clickability. However, when there is no more images in a certain direction, i set the class to disabled.

```
.disabled
{
    cursor:default;
}
```

However, the hover pseudo class takes precedence here, and changes the cursor to pointer. How can I prevent :hover to set the cursor to pointer when .disabled is set? Is it at all possible?

Comment: Setting cursor "what the mouse cursor should look like **when pointing here**: in a :hover rule "how to style things **when pointing here**" is rather redundant.

Comment: @David Dorward Hmm, you lost me there.. If you could rephrase that a bit?

Comment: I expanded on David's point a little in my answer.

Comment: Cursor only has any impact when the pointer is pointing at the element. :hover only has any impact when the pointer is pointing at the element. So foo:hover { cursor: bar } means "When the pointer is over the element, make the cursor 'bar' when it is over the element". The :hover is pointless.

Comment: Haha you are totally right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!important`.

```
.disabled {
    cursor:default!important;
}
```

IE6's `!important` implementation is buggy, so if you need to support it you might just be better off re-ordering your rules to get the required precedence for the `.disabled` class.

[David Dorward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/david-dorward) raised an interesting point to note in the comments.  Applying a value to *cursor* in a `:hover` pseudo-class is completely redundant.  The following to rules have exactly the same effect:

```
.mylink { cursor:pointer; }
.mylink:hover { cursor:pointer; }
```

Therefore, you should avoid setting *cursor* in a pseudo class and stick to

```
.mylink { cursor:hand; }
```

Comment: IE6 does support !important (although there are some bugs relating to it) and `hand` is invalid CSS. (That said, !important is a one-use sledgehammer and is almost always the wrong answer (the right answer being "Get your specificity straight")

Comment: @David: you're quite right, I forgot that `hand` was a MS proprietary value for *cursor*.  I do agree that re-ordering rules is usually the better solution.  Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 3):

Add also

```
.disabled:hover {
   cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks man.

(accepting answer when I can, some time limit)